# What is hard_timeout in PHP Core config?

Tags: php, php-7.1

Available since PHP 7.1.0, `hard_timeout` have 2 seconds as default value and accept integgers as value.

At documentation, http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.hard-timeout, there is no additional information available.

What's the difference between other "timeout" flags and `hard_timeout`  in PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP timeout will try to kill the application "softly".

In case it can't, by any reason, the hard timeout will kill by force.

Info from here: http://php-news.ctrl-f5.net/message/php.internals/92559

Comment: I think there are important comments inside this message on your link that can improve your answer, such as 
"It removes 'exit_on_timeout ini directive, and introduces hard_timeout" instead.

Comment: Does the integer's set in minutes? The default value seems to be "2", so is it 2 minutes?

Comment: Seconds. So two minutes would be 120 seconds. It doesn't mean that your application will be killed in two seconds of execution, but if after 2 seconds the "soft kill" won't work, the hard kill will be executed.

Comment: "Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, sleep, etc... **is not included**"